# API not get called for already visited pages in dev express datagrid server side pagination

Tags: devexpress, devextreme-angular

I've created server-side pagination using dev express Datagrid, I'm fetching data properly but I saw that API not getting called if I visit that page again,

Suppose, I visited page 1, page 2 then it fetches data properly, again if I click on page 1 then data displayed in the table is proper but API not getting called.

is it like, it stores all the fetched data or I'm doing wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[cacheEnabled]="false"**

above attribute disables the cache on the dx data grid and calls API in serverside pagination every time you change the page.